# Why won't SourceTree for Mac OS let me branch the same way twice?

Tags: git, branch

I'm new to Git and I'm using SourceTree for Mac OS and have a question about branching. This is for a very small project, and it's my first time using version control. I only have a very basic understanding of it so far. The first branch I made by clicking on "Branch" to create a branch from my second commit, and that worked fine. However, the second time I made a branch was off of my first commit, and SourceTree wouldn't let me do it the same way. I had to use Checkout instead of Branch and it created a detached head and then I had to name the new branch. I'm wondering why it would not allow me to create my branches in the same way. Thanks!

Comment: I think some more info is required here - when you created the first branch did you also check it out? or were you on master? do you have a tree diagram to help us visualize your commits?

Answer (score 1):

If you have your master branch with 2 commits and you create the first branch from the second commit your HEAD is pointing to the same commit as the master branch and the branch command will simply start from there.

If you want to create the second branch with the first commit as starting point, you have no choice to first move your HEAD on the first commit by checking it out (the consequence is that your HEAD will be detached from the master branch because it is pointing to a different commit). When your HEAD is pointing the appropriate commit you can proceed to the branch creation and this new branch will start from the first commit.

The process of creating a branch is the same in both situations, the only difference is that the first time your starting point is the last commit of the master branch and your HEAD is attached to this branch (that means that HEAD and master are pointing to the same commit). And in the second process you want to start a branch from a different commit, that simply require to move your HEAD on another commit and the result is indicated by a **detached HEAD**.

Hope this will help you to better understand the logic behind git.

If you want to get further into git, check this tutorial: [Learn git branching](http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/)

This tutorial is really awesome and will help you a lot to better understand the most important mechanisms behind git.